# Matlab data: Finding average of each column in plot

Tags: matlab, plot, average

I am a beginner at using MATLAB. I have data which has 17 columns showing wave heights and wind data over a period of 7 years.
First 4 columns are the years (2005-2011), month, day and hour respectively.
And the next columns are the respective recordings.

I found a useful script here to plot these columns.

```
fid = fopen('wam1.txt','r'); 
C = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f','headerlines',4,'commentstyle','--');
fclose(fid);
x = C{1}; y1 = C{5}; y2 = C{3};
plot(x,y1)
```

Now, the graph consists of (for example) wind speed on Y axis and year (2005-2011) on X axis. And I have to find the average of wind speed for each year.
Could anyone help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a vector and you want to find the mean of each row try mean(A, 2). If you want to find the mean of only the last columns then mean(A(:, 5:end), 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to plot the values of `y1` the solution would be very simple.

```
mean(y1)
```

Will give you the average of y1.

If you want to do this by year, this will let you loop through the years and store the mean in a vector called `result`.

```
count = 0;
for t = unique(x)
   count = count+1;
   result(count) = mean(y1(x==t)); % Or just result(t)
end
result
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I need to find the average for "each year" and that is not possible through mean(y1) as it presents the average of the entire dataset irrespective of the year.

Comment: @RohitKulkarni I have updated my post, did not have the chance to test but this should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If there are the same number of values for each year, and they are in order (e.g. all values for 2005 first, then all values for 2006...) you could use reshape:

```
y1 = reshape(y1,365,7); mean(y1)
```

Otherwise, you can calculate for each year:

```
mean(y1(x==2005))
```

Comment: If the data is sufficiently structured, the first solution mentioned here is definately the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! The values are in order but they are different for each year. I checked and the method given by @DennisJaheruddin and you work perfectly.